# AWS-SDK Cloudwatch MaxQueryTimeRangeExceed

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatch

I am new to AWS SDK (and nodejs) and I am trying to get cloudwatch's getMetricData to work. Im using a simple Cloudwatch query to grab the CPU utilization of an instance. But no matter what I do, I just keep getting this

```
{
  ResponseMetadata: { RequestId: '5253fbfc-5aa2-4dfb-871b-1453f8610d80' },
  MetricDataResults: [
    {
      Id: 'q1',
      Label: 'q1',
      Timestamps: [],
      Values: [],
      StatusCode: 'Complete',
      Messages: []
    }
  ],
  Messages: [
    {
      Code: 'MaxQueryTimeRangeExceeded',
      Value: 'Max time window exceeded for query'
    }
  ]
}
```

here is my code

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.loadFromPath("./config.json");

var cloudwatch = new AWS.CloudWatch({apiVersion: "2010-08-01"});

var params = {

    StartTime: new Date('june 06, 2022 17:30'),
    EndTime: new Date('june 06, 2022 18:00'), 
    MetricDataQueries: [ 
      {
        Id: 'q1', 
        Expression: "SELECT AVG(CPUUtilization) FROM SCHEMA(\"AWS/EC2\", InstanceId) WHERE InstanceId = 'i-**********'",
        Period: '600'
      },
    ],
    
  };
  cloudwatch.getMetricData(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); 
    else     console.log(data);           
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can only request the latest 3 hours of data using the `SELECT ...` syntax.

From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_GetMetricData.html),

> Metrics Insights queries can query only the most recent three hours of
> metric data.

Looks like you're only getting the `CPUUtilization` for a single instance. You can get that with the `MetricStat` object. Something like this:

```
var params = {

    StartTime: new Date('june 06, 2022 17:30'),
    EndTime: new Date('june 06, 2022 18:00'), 
    MetricDataQueries: [ 
      {
      Id: 'm1',
      Label: 'CPUUtilization',
      MetricStat: {
        Metric: {
          Namespace: 'AWS/EC2',
          MetricName: 'CPUUtilization',
          Dimensions: [
            {
              Name: 'InstanceId',
              Value: 'i-xxxxxxxxxx'
            }
          ]
        },
        Period: '600',
        Stat: 'Average'
      }
    },
    ],
    
  };
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I was facing the same issue and wasn't aware of the 3 hours limit.