# I want to get metrics of multiple ec2s at once from aws cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, metrics

aws cloudwatch can use get_metric_data and get_metric_statistics for single ec2.

However, it is impossible to fetch information from multiple ec2s at once.

How can I get multiple ec2 metrics with one api call?

Metrics should be separated by ec2.

example)

1. get single ec2 data (success)

```
import boto3
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil.tz import tzutc
session = boto3.Session(profile_name="XXXXXXXXXX")
client = session.client('cloudwatch', 'ap-northeast-2')
response = client.get_metric_data(
    MetricDataQueries=[
        {
            'Id': 'cpuUtilization',
            'MetricStat': {
                'Metric': {
                    'Namespace': 'AWS/EC2',
                    'MetricName': 'CPUUtilization',
                    'Dimensions': [
                        {
                            'Name': 'InstanceId',
                            'Value': 'i-XXXXXXXXX'
                        },
                    ]
                },
                'Period': 60,
                'Stat': 'Average'
            }
        }
    ],
    StartTime=datetime(2022, 7, 7, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzutc()),
    EndTime=datetime(2022, 7, 7, 23, 59, 59, tzinfo=tzutc())
)
print(response)

RESULT:
{'MetricDataResults': [{'Id': 'cpuUtilization',
```

2. get single ec2 data (fail)

```
import boto3
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil.tz import tzutc
session = boto3.Session(profile_name="XXXXXXXXXX")
client = session.client('cloudwatch', 'ap-northeast-2')
response = client.get_metric_data(
    MetricDataQueries=[
        {
            'Id': 'cpuUtilization',
            'MetricStat': {
                'Metric': {
                    'Namespace': 'AWS/EC2',
                    'MetricName': 'CPUUtilization',
                    'Dimensions': [
                        {
                            'Name': 'InstanceId',
                            'Value': 'i-XXXXXXXXX'
                        },
                    ]
                },
                'Period': 60,
                'Stat': 'Average'
            }
        },
        {
            'Id': 'cpuUtilization',
            'MetricStat': {
                'Metric': {
                    'Namespace': 'AWS/EC2',
                    'MetricName': 'CPUUtilization',
                    'Dimensions': [
                        {
                            'Name': 'InstanceId',
                            'Value': 'i-XXXXXXXXX'
                        },
                    ]
                },
                'Period': 60,
                'Stat': 'Average'
            }
        }
    ],
    StartTime=datetime(2022, 7, 7, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzutc()),
    EndTime=datetime(2022, 7, 7, 23, 59, 59, tzinfo=tzutc())
)
print(response)

RESULT:
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the GetMetricData operation: The values for parameter id in MetricDataQueries are not unique.
```

Answer (score 0):

[AWS-SDK Cloudwatch MaxQueryTimeRangeExceed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72820864/aws-sdk-cloudwatch-maxquerytimerangeexceed)

I was able to find the answer I was looking for in the link above. But it has a 3 hour limit. If you have another good way, please share.

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.loadFromPath("./config.json");

var cloudwatch = new AWS.CloudWatch({apiVersion: "2010-08-01"});

var params = {

    StartTime: new Date('june 06, 2022 17:30'),
    EndTime: new Date('june 06, 2022 18:00'), 
    MetricDataQueries: [ 
      {
        Id: 'q1', 
        Expression: "SELECT AVG(CPUUtilization) FROM SCHEMA(\"AWS/EC2\", InstanceId) WHERE InstanceId = 'i-**********'",
        Period: '600'
      },
    ],
    
  };
  cloudwatch.getMetricData(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); 
    else     console.log(data);           
  });
```